How to change the outer color/shadow of a View?

I'm trying to make an image picker.
I have 2 views.
<View className="flex-1 w-full h-full relative items-center justify-center">
  <View style={{
    height: 300,
    width: "full",
    position: "absolute"
  }}></View>
</View>

I want the inner View to drop a shadow outside of it like in the picture. I try to use shadow, but it doesn't seem to work.
In react I have
box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px #ffffff77; but I don't know how to achieve this in react-native.
